# Excel - Select range depending on cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I want to select a row range, which I've been doing manually until now. However as data grows, I've tried to select the row according to the relative worksheet, but don't know how to. Here's an example.

```
Purchased apples spreadsheet

Buyer | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 
John  | 3     | 1     | 1        
Adam  | 2     | 3     | 3                
Anna  | 1     | 3     | 2             


Price Spreadsheet

Item  | Price
Apple | 10
```

Now I need to build a third sheet containing the money totals, so I have something like this:

```
Totals

Buyer | Credit | Debit | Total
John  | Formula|Formula| Formula
Anna  | Formula|Formula| Formula
Adam  | Formula|Formula| Formula
```

So the manual way would be to copy the formulas and manually replace the ranges for each user, so they all match the other tables. What I would like to do is select the rows where the first cell in the row has the same value as the `Totals`. In other words:

1. Search A:A
2. Find John in `Purchased apples spreadsheet`
3. Found John in row 7
4. Select range 7:7.

Is that possible to do?